# excel rowheight - a bug here?

Tags: vba, excel, row-height

Excel seems to work with the row heights in the following (il)logic:

If you refer to a **single cell** and your cell is defined "Wrap Text" and the row height is "Autofit":

- When you enter more characters than what can fit to the cell width the row in the cell is changed automatically and in the end, when you press "Enter", the row height is expanded so that the whole text is visible.

If you refer to **combined cells** and your cell combination is "Wrap text" and "Autofit":

- When you enter more characters than what can fit to the combined cells' width the row is **NOT** changed automatically and after "Enter" the row height is **NOT** adjusted to show the whole text.

I think this is not logical.

What would be the trick to get excel to automatically adjust the row height also in the case of "Wrap Text" combined cells? Any VBA solutions? (Basically you could, maybe, count how many line changes the combined cell has and adjust the rows.height property accordingly but...

Comment: You could use the worksheet change event and have some logic to assess the amount of characters the cell has and resize the row according to this. Not perfect but beats the default. Hopefully someone has a more elegant solution.

Comment: Not logical.. maybe, but the problem with merged cells is more difficult than it seems. Imagine a merged area with many rows... How to affect the other rows when autofitting? Imagine many merged areas near each other and each having a different number of rows.... It's very complicated.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't support this feature https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/212010/you-cannot-use-the-autofit-feature-for-rows-or-columns-that-contain-merged-cells-in-excel.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I understand that the row height definition may be complex with merged cells. However, in my case the merged cells blocks are always only I row high so in this case automatic row height adjustment would be equal with the case of one cell only.

Comment: ...back to the drawing board...Cheers!